# Enable text file uploads

Tags: wordpress

Added the following filter to functions.php in my theme:

```
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_myme_types', 1, 1 );
function my_myme_types( $mime_types ) {
  $mime_types['txt'] = 'text/plain';
  return $mime_types;
}
```

but when I try upload a text file to Media Library I still get 'Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.'

My Wordpress version is 5.2.

Answer (score 2):

This should work without any additional function. I just tried with test txt file and it is working fine. There must be some kind of conflict in your code.

Comment: yes I was able to load a text file on some other WordPress site